# Robot Localization not transforms from input's frame_id

Tags: navigation, ekf, ros-kinetic, robot-localization, ekf-localization-node

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am trying to fuse the output of ORB-SLAM2 (as PoseWithCovarianceStamped msg) into ekf_localization_node instance. The frame_id of the pose msg is an optical frame called "zed_optical_frame".

I want to get the output in the standard X-forward Y-left Z-up frame.

In the TF tree I have "base_link" -> "zed_center" -> "zed_optical_frame". The "zed_optical_frame" is just a rotation from "zed_center" with RPY=(-PI/2,0.0,-PI/2).

Still, I get the output in the same optical frame as the input.

I made a test and left only this input to the ekf_localization_node, when I turned on the Differential flag.

I'm running on Jetson TX2 with Ubuntu 16.04 and ROS Kinetic.

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/301258/robot-localization-not-transforms-from-input%27s-frame_id/) by [orsalmon](https://answers.ros.org/users/25030/orsalmon/) on ROS Answers with karma: 18 on 2018-08-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I would request that you update the question with your config and sample input messages from every sensor input, but in this case, I can probably answer it anyway.

Just so we're clear: the package outputs the pose of the camera, and the camera's transform is relative to `base_link`? This is, sadly, not a use case that is well-supported by `robot_localization`.

The state estimation nodes in `r_l` always transform velocity and acceleration data into the `base_link_frame` frame, and always transform pose data into the `world_frame` (typically *map* or *odom*) frame.

Let's say you get a pose message in the *zed_optical_frame*, and that pose says we are at `(10, 0)`. That will be interpreted as a pose that is 10 meters *in front of* your robot's camera, so whatever way your robot is facing, we'll try to fuse a pose that is 10 meters in front of it.

What we really need to be doing is transforming the *base_link*->*zed_optical_frame* transform into the world frame, then applying that transformed offset to the camera's pose data. I suppose any time we're fusing pose data and the required transform "crosses" the `world_frame`->`base_link_frame` transform, we should treat the data differently. But I don't know if that will get implemented before `fuse`, the spiritual successor to `r_l`, is done.

In the meantime, you have a few options:

1. In the camera driver, obtain the *base_link* -> *zed_optical_frame* transform (which is probably static), and store that. Call it *T*. Every time you generate a measurement from the `ORB-SLAM2` package, rotate `T` by the robot's current orientation, and then apply the inverse of that transform to the camera's pose data. Then change the `frame_id` to whatever your EKF `world_frame` is, and publish.
2. Use `differential` mode, but then the filter will assume that data is in the `base_link_frame` frame. Not great, I know.
3. If `ORB_SLAM2` produces velocity data, fuse that instead. The covariance in your state estimate will grow without bound, though.

---

Originally posted by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) with karma: 13689 on 2018-09-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1